# Switch off git history hint in ST3

Tags: git, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Today Sublime Text 3 started show me a grey colored hint, consisted information who and when this line has been added plus the comment to commit on each cursored line. How to switch it off? (On the image below I highlighted this hint with red line)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you're bumping into a new (as of the time of this writing) feature in the [GitGutter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GitGutter) package that [displays blame annotations](http://jisaacks.github.io/GitGutter/settings/#line-annotation) at the end of the line. The setting in question is `show_line_annotation`, which has a default setting that enables it as long as word wrap is turned off, which it probably is for code.

Comment: Thanks! I set show_line_annotation to false in GitGutter settings file and it helped me!